# Mongoose / Node : How to add an object to an array?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a problem when I try to update an array with Mongoose/Node.

I want to add my new price for example, req.body value is : { price: 12 } or req.body is : { description: 'my description' } but when I do this the total array is replace by just my new object ! :/

Here is my model:

```
const restaurantSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  userId: { type: Object, required: true },
  name: { type: String },
  menus: [{
    name: { type: String },
    price: { type: String },
    description: { type: String },
  }],
})
```

And my node Js code :

```
const menuUpdate = req.body;
const menuId = req.params.menuId;

const userId = userIdFromToken(req);

const filter = {
  userId: userId,
  "menus._id": menuId
};

const update = { $set: { "menus.$": menuUpdate } };

const options = {
  upsert: true,
  new: true
};

Restaurant.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, options).then(() => {
  return res.status(204).json({ message: "Menus updated " });
});
```

Thanks for your help,

David

====

I change my code with the help of @aks, like this...

```
    const menuUpdate = req.body;

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(menuUpdate)) {
      this.menuKey = `${key}`;
      this.menuValue = `${value}`;
    }

    if (this.menuKey === 'name') {
      this.update = { $set: { "menus.$.name": this.menuValue } };
    }

    if (this.menuKey === 'price') {
      this.update = { $set: { "menus.$.price": this.menuValue } };
    }

    if (this.menuKey === 'description') {
      this.update = { $set: { "menus.$.description": this.menuValue } };
    }

    const menuId = req.params.menuId;

    const userId = userIdFromToken(req);

    const filter = { 
      userId: userId,
      'menus._id': menuId,
    };

    const options = { 
      upsert: true, 
      new: true 
    };

    Restaurant
      .findOneAndUpdate( 
        filter, 
        this.update,
        options,
      )
    .then ( () => {
      return res.status(204).json({ message: 'Menus updated ' });
    });
```

Is there a way to simplify that without if ?

Comment: Reason is you already set the array of objects in the schema. And on your db query, you will update all object in the array which is not the plain array. It is the collection of array of object.

You have to update the key one by one

Comment: Thank you for your answer Aks, how can I update my keys one by one ? 
Actually my req.body return me an object like that : { name: 'toto' } or { price: 12 } or { description: 'my menus is done' } 
I would like to add that key in my array and it is where I'm stuck ! :/

I try to replace $push by $set, the error disapears but all my array seems replaced by my new key value !

Comment: Got it. For that case you have to send some identifier from api calls by which you can set exact value. Lets say I want to update only the price value then I have to send the full menus array with only updated the price value, rest other values are old

Comment: other way is lets say on menus array you have 10 objects. every objects has its index. SO send the index on request so that you know that on specific index I have to update which key

Answer (score 0):

Your Node code

```
menus: [{
    name: "toto",
    price: 25,
    description: "custom sweet",
  }]
```

Now You have to update only the price from 25 to 45 for that you have to send the whole array.

So you have to simple set the array with this value

And if you go to other approach

then on req.body add one more parameter i.e menuIndex: 2

And on you update request make the condition if menuIndex is 2 then update specific column

```
const menuUpdate = req.body;
const menuId = req.params.menuId;

const userId = userIdFromToken(req);

const filter = {
  userId: userId,
  "menus._id": menuId
};

let update = {};
if (req.body.menuIndex === 1) {
  update = { $set: { "menus.$.name": req,body.val} };
}

if (req.body.menuIndex === 2) {
  update = { $set: { "menus.$.price": req,body.val
} };
}

if (req.body.menuIndex === 3) {
  update = { $set: { "menus.$.description": req,body.val} };
}

const options = {
  upsert: true,
  new: true
};

Restaurant.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, options).then(() => {
  return res.status(204).json({ message: "Menus updated " });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I change my code with your helpful one, and it's working !
I put my new code at the end of my question...
Is there a way to do it without the if ? :-) Actually it's working, but I have many others values (that I don't put in the example, and the code will be long and repetitive so I would like to find a way to optimize it a bit...)

Comment: Okay its also easy. get the array of length. lets say you have 1000 keys. Now on api call send the index which you want to update
On node.js query update that index with the value which you have attach on the parameter

Comment: Thank you again, is it possible to have an example ? I'm very new to node and mongoose, it's a bit like my brain will explode every day...